# What would be the most efficient way to check that a name is within a list of possible words?

Tags: algorithm, performance

For example, let's imagine that you have the following name ['Michael', 'Scott'] and you want to check that most of the words that make up the name are contained in the following list of names and surnames:
['Pam', 'Michael', 'Jin', 'Schrute', ...]

PS: The list is very large, greater than 10,000 words

Comment: Binary search on a sorted array is O(logN) and lookup in a hashtable is O(1)

Comment: It consists of checking if a word of the name is in the list, if it is affirmative, the number of words or tokens that the name contains is counted, if there are a large number of words that match the list, the name is correct

Comment: It's not clear that your data input format - is a pair of  tuples in a list [('first_name', 'last_name') ...]  Can you cofirm?

Comment: The input format is a list of strings that can be of any length

Answer (score 0):

You have to save those 10k+ words in unordered_set(in c++ for example), which means it will be hashed, and checking if the name is contained in the list will be O(1) ~ O(log(max_len(word))).